# Jquery method stops to works after hide and show with vuejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, typeahead.js

I have input filed

```
<div class="section" v-if="active==1">
    <input type="text"  name="topic" id="topic" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false">
</div>
```

and i have typeahead

```
$('#topic').typeahead({
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 0
    },
    {
        name: 'topics',
        source: substringMatcher(topics)
    },
);
```

When page load, typeahead works fine, but when i set active with vuejs to 0 and then back to 1 (hide and show .section) then typeahead stops to work

Comment: You are usimg `v-if` which destroys and reconstructs the element. Try using `v-show` instead which just triggers the css `display:none` property

Comment: Thanks, that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's answer along with reason

You are binding the typeAhead handler to the input element using **direct** 
binding which attaches the handler only to the elements that already exists.

That's the reason it works for the first time when the page loads.

You are using `v-if` which destroys and recreates the element. since the element is getting recreated dynamically
the typehead handler is not bound anymore to the subsequently rendered input elements

if you just want to show/hide the input element using   `v-show` is better as it just toggles the css `display` property
and you dont have to worry about binding of the handler as imput element is not getting removed anymore